# cp and set new user

Tags: cp, chown

I configure linux servers with some regularty. And then copy with `ssh-copy-id` my public key to the root user (`/root/.ssh`) and edit `authorized-keys`.

If I install additional services, sometimes private users are created and I like  to ssh to them directly. Then I either have to repeat the `ssh-copy-id` + edit `authorized-keys` process (and account must have password to login), or `cp -R` my root `.ssh` and then run `chown -R someuser`.

I can tell `cp` to preserve ownership of a file, but is there a way to tell it (when run as root) to create as a someuser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cpio` with the `--owner` option:

```
cd /root
find .ssh -print | cpio -pdmv --owner=someuser ~someuser/
```

If the accounts often  have/need a password, you can also copy your public key file to a new file and edit that locally and then use:

```
ssh-copy-id -i edited_pub_file someuser@server
```

that way you don't have to edit the public key data afterwards (you can do that anyway for your initial `ssh-copy-d` for root.

Comment: Not sure your second example would work, as you would be in ~someuser/ when you run the cp command.`tar cf - .ssh | su -l someuser -c "tar xf -"` should work.

Comment: @geedoubleya Actually I thought that wouldn't work either but I tried it before I posted and it worked. The permissions owner on the source are 700/root and on the targetuser `.ssh` 700/targetuser.

Comment: Interesting. Could you try `su -l someuser -c "cp -r /root/.ssh/ ~someuser/"` instead?

Comment: @geedoubleya I was copying the previously copied (.ssh) from trying the find command, into itself, it was never copying `/root/.ssh` thanks for insinstance, I removed this 'non-ternative'.

Comment: No problem, I am sure you will have ample opportunity to return the favour!